# How to detect a PR raised for a branch in Teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity, bitbucket, pull-request

e.g. let's say I have a `master` branch for a repo in Bitbucket and a developer developing in `feature_branch_1` raises a PR to merge into `master`.

I want to be able to detect a PR has been raised for `master` and then run some tests on it. I think this is possible through some combination of Branch Specification in VCS root, VCS Trigger in TeamCity. Would like some help on the exact values to be used in these fields to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at these 2 links:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/

https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000788930-Build-trigger-branch-filter-for-pull-requests

I believe they will help you out (2nd one more likely).